# what does this query mean

Tags: mysql, not-exists

what does this query mean

```
  select fname, lname  
  from Owner 
  where not exists 
      (select fname, lname 
            from Trainer)
```

what i understand :it returns fname and lname from table owner where these names not exsit in table trainer ?
am i right?

Answer (score 3):

Find the names of people who exist in the `Owner` table but not in the `Trainer` table.

Comment: That probably was an intent, but a forgetful author of the query did not link the sub-select with the top-level select. The query returns all rows from `Owner` if `Trainer` is empty, or no rows otherwise.

Comment: @9000: Very nice catch. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: but when i run the query no result is shown although both tables are different

Comment: @Wizzy: As @9000 pointed out, the query as written will only return results if there are no rows in the `Trainer` table. What does `select count(*) from Trainer` return? If it returns a number > 0, then the query in your question returns no results.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty lame way to get a list of everyone from the `owner` table that doesn't exist in the `trainer` table.

So, if the `Owner` table contains

```
----------------
fname   | lname
----------------
clark   | kent
lois    | lane
peter   | parker
```

and the Trainer table contains

```
----------------
fname   | lname
----------------
peter   | parker
hal     | jordan
```

You should get a result set:

```
----------------
fname   | lname
----------------
clark   | kent
lois    | lane
```

**Update**

Actually, your query won't return anything if there are any records at all in the Trainer table. You should probably be using:

```
select fname, lname
from Owners
where not exists (
    select fname, lname 
    from trainers 
    where fname=Owners.fname 
          and lname=Owners.lname
    )
```

Comment: It is lame because it is inefficient. It would be better to do it with a join.

Comment: but when i run the query no result is shown although both tables are different

Comment: Is it? I'm not sure about MySQL, but MSSQL and Oracle deal pretty well with this, often making it *more* efficient than the join.

Comment: @Wizzy, see the comment in the top answer - it explains why the specific query is broken (which doesn't mean that `EXISTS` doesn't work as expected in general).

Comment: @Byron Of course, but the question is so elementary that I avoided confusing the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The query has two parts: the 'select' and the 'where'.
Look at the where part first:

```
  where not exists 
      (select fname, lname from Trainer)
```

This where clause evaluates to 'true' if there is nothing in the Trainer table, and to 'false' if there is something there. Now look at the 'select' part:

```
  select fname, lname from Owners
```

This selects all rows from the 'Owners' table.

Putting this together: the query selects all rows from the Owner table IF (and only if) there is nothing in the Trainer table -- and absolutely nothing if there is.